# How to get good performances when using symfony 2 ACL system with a large number of object?

Tags: php, symfony, acl

In our project we are using symfony 2 ACL system to control access to the entities stored in a database (Postgresql).

Everything works fine until we want to check permission on large quantity of object (a few hundreds). Then the performance are getting bad. On some pages the number of query to the database is above 4000. This number is in fact in direct relation with the number of entities in our database. The more it grows the more query on this page need to be done.

Is there a way to check the user's authorization on many object while conserving descent performance (keeping the number of query to the db low)?

Comment: You should try to use voters instead http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

Answer (score 0):

There is way to actually load acl data related to one or many different entities. The system tries to load them all in a small amount of query and then keeps the data around so that they can be reused without going to the database again.

```
private function loadBlogPostsAcls($blogPostRepository)
{
    $oids = array();
    foreach ($blogPostRepository->findBy(array(), array('date' => 'asc')) as $blogPost) {
        $oids[] = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($blogPost);
    }

    $this->aclProvider->findAcls($oids);
}
```